# How to focus invalid input field

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

This is my script for form validation. i have used two forms here. when i focus text field, the cursor is jumping between two fields. http://jsfiddle.net/q9Xq6/

```
var $ = {
    getById: function (e) {
        return document.getElementById(e);
    },
    isEmpty: function (e, m) {
        var e = $.getById(e);
        var isValid = /[^.]/.test(e.value);
        $.showMessage(isValid, e, m);
        return isValid;
    },
    isAlpha: function (e, m) {
        var e = $.getById(e);
        var isValid = /[a-zA-Z]/.test(e.value);
        $.showMessage(isValid, e, m);
        return isValid;
    },
    isNumeric: function (e, m) {
        var e = $.getById(e);
        var isValid = /[0-9]/.test(e.value);
        $.showMessage(isValid, e, m);
        return isValid;
    },
    showMessage: function (valid, e, m) {
        if (!valid) {
            e.className = 'invalid';
            console.log(m);
            setTimeout(function () {
                e.focus();
            }, 100);

        } else {
            e.className = '';
        }
    },
    _onBlur: function (form, event, func) {
        var form = $.getById(form);
        var elements = form.getElementsByTagName('*');
        for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
            elements[i][event] = func;
        }
    }
}


var abc = function () {
    return (
        $.isEmpty('name', 'empty message') &&
        $.isAlpha('name', 'alpha message') &&
        $.isEmpty('phone', 'empty message') &&
        $.isNumeric('phone', 'alpha message')
    );
}
var abc1 = function () {
    return (
        $.isEmpty('name1', 'empty message1') &&
        $.isAlpha('name1', 'alpha message1') &&
        $.isEmpty('phone1', 'empty message1') &&
        $.isNumeric('phone1', 'alpha message1')
    );
}
$.getById("form").onsubmit = abc;
$._onBlur("form", "onblur", abc);

$.getById("form1").onsubmit = abc1;
$._onBlur("form1", "onblur", abc1);
//$._onBlur("form","onkeyup",abc);
```

Comment: The link to your code isn't working

Comment: paste your code in the question section

Comment: i could not put jsfiddele link. this is my actual url http://jsfiddle.net/q9Xq6/

Comment: @SathishRG - I put it in for you.

Comment: Please frame  your question properly/..

Comment: please check my jsfiddle url. jsfiddle.net/q9Xq6

Answer (score 0):

Here we go... Just try this,

```
 function validation1(reg2)
 {

    if(document.reg2.name.value=="")
 {
  alert("'Name' empty or not in proper length");
 document.reg2.name.focus();
 return false;
 }
 }
```

here in the above code document.reg2.name.focus(); is used to focus invalid input field,     where,

1. reg2 is the name of your form,
2. name is the text field name of the form.

Comment: my problem is here, the cursor is jumping between two input fields. please check this link jsfiddle.net/q9Xq6   here  I have added two form separately. focus first input field than fourth input field. now you can find the actual issue which I am facing... any way thanks for you post :)